# GeoJSON with a geometry property in ol3

Tags: openlayers-3

In ol3, having a GeoJSON with one of the properties called `geometry` fails:

```
var geojsonObject = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]
        },
        "properties": {
            "prop0": "value0",
            "geometry": "This is a point"
        }
    }]
};

features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject);

console.log(features[0].getGeometry());
console.log(features[0].get('prop0'));
```

Is this legal? Should it be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, having a feature property named geometry is valid GeoJSON. The GeoJSON specification explicitly states that the

> value of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a JSON null value)

OpenLayers 3 stores the geometry as a normal property on a Feature, with the default name `geometry`. When reading the feature in your question, the `geometry` GeoJSON feature member is first written to the `geometry` property, but then overwritten by the `geometry` GeoJSON property member.

To avoid this collision, the geometry must be stored with a different property name. You can control that with the `geometryName` option to [`ol.format.GeoJSON`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html):

```
var geoJSONFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    geometryName: 'actualGeometry'
});
geoJSONFormat.readFeatures(geojsonObject);
```